# Extending enumerated properties in derived class

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to use enumerated properties with can be extended in derived classes so new properties can be introduced.

Using enum fails due to type mismatch, and the only other idea I can think of is to define static const int's in the header files.

Is there any better approach to this in C++?

A scenario that I would like to be able to use would be something like:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A {
 public:
  typedef enum {
    Prop1 = 10,
    Prop2,
    Prop_last,
  } Property;

  void SetProp (Property p) { a = p; }
  Property GetProp() { return a; }
 private:
  Property a;
};

class D1 : public A {
 public:
  typedef enum {
    Prop3,
    Prop4,
  } Property;
};

class D2 : public A {
 public:
  typedef enum {
    Prop5,
    Prop6,
  } Property;
};

int main()
{
  D1 d1;
  D2 d2;

  d1.SetProp(A::Prop1);
  printf ("%d\n", d1.GetProp());
  d1.SetProp(D1::Prop3);  // compilation error: wrong type
  printf ("%d\n", d1.GetProp());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since the language does not allow what you are trying, it might be better to ask what your real problem is. Maybe there is a better solution to the real problem.

Comment: Why not a map of properties for the class? Why is the enumeration important?